# How can I hide a file with a particular name from the sidebar in Sublime Text?

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

Note that I am not looking to hide files with a particular extension, but rather a particular filename.

Example, I want to hide all files with names starting with 'foo'.

This includes: foo.bar, foo.txt, foo_234.bar, fooblah.git etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have many places you could do this, but the two most common are that you never want to see certain files regardless of project or you just don't want to see certain files in certain projects. I've covered both below.

To never see them in the sidebar, regardless of project or folder structure you open, you can modify you user settings. To quickly access the user settings config file in the Mac version, use the menu "Sublime Text 2" -> "Preferences" -> "Settings - User")

Here's an example user configuration file to not display any files in the tree that begin with "foo":

```
{
    "color_scheme": "Packages/User/Railscasts.tmTheme",
    "font_size": 12.0,

    //File patters to exclude from sidebar display
    "file_exclude_patterns": 
    [
    "foo*"
    ]

}
```

If you use projects and just want to filter files for a specific project, here's a sample project configuration file to not display any files in that project that begin with "foo":

```
{
    "folders":
    [
        {
            "path": ".",

            //File patters to exclude from sidebar display
            "file_exclude_patterns": 
            [
            "foo*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Happy editing using your tidier sidebar. :)

Answer (score 3):

If you have a project, you can edit your project settings to have a `file_exclude_patterns` entry, like:

```
{
    "folders":
    [
        {
            "path": ".",

            // Patterns of files to exclude from sidebar
            "file_exclude_patterns": [
                "foo*"  // Exclude all files beginning with `foo`
                ]
        }
    ]
}
```

There is also a similar `folder_exclude_patterns` to exclude folders from the sidebar.